# Get Java Robot to type what is in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, awtrobot

I have found Java code online that will let me use the Robot class to do various things. I am using it currently to try to automate a database dump that requires repetitive entering of file names, in this case numbers. No, I cannot just do a batch file rename at the end, they have to be named independently. I don't want to do this 13,000 times (the size of my database) so I am attempting to automate it. What I need that I don't have is the Robot code to type what is in the For loop. My code is below:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotClicker
{
  Robot robot = new Robot();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
  {
    new RobotClicker();
  }

  public RobotClicker() throws AWTException
  {
    robot.setAutoDelay(40);
    robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);

    robot.delay(4000);
    robot.mouseMove(144, 400);
    robot.delay(500);

    leftClick();
    robot.delay(500);
    leftClick();    

    robot.delay(500);
    for(int i = 856; i>858;i++ ){
        String holding = "test ";
        type(holding);
    }

    robot.mouseMove(450, 480);
    robot.delay(500);

    leftClick();
    robot.delay(500);
    leftClick();    

    robot.delay(1000);
    System.exit(0);
  }

  private void leftClick()
  {
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(200);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(200);
  }

  private void type(int i)
  {
    robot.delay(40);
    robot.keyPress(i);
    robot.keyRelease(i);
  }

  private void type(String s)
  {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
      int code = b;
      // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
      if (code > 96 && code < 123) code = code - 32;
      robot.delay(40);
      robot.keyPress(code);
      robot.keyRelease(code);
    }
  }
}
```

The file names are just numbers. I need the for loop to produce the next number in the sequence, and then the Robot to type it out, repeat ad nauseam. At the moment the Robot does the moving and the clicking just fine, but nothing types out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I ended up with. I start the database dump (which brings up the "save" dialog box. I moved the dialog box to the upper left corner of the screen. The screen "X" and "Y" positions are based on my screen and where I moved the dialog box to.), then start the robot program. It moves the mouse to the "File name" part of the dialog box (based on where I moved the box to), clicks the left mouse button once, enters the next number in the sequence, then moves the mouse to left click where the "save" button is. It waits for a brief period then repeats. It did the entirety of the 2 databases overnight so we didn't have to mess with it anymore. Yay technology!

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotClicker {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        new RobotClicker();
    }

    public RobotClicker() throws AWTException {
        robot.setAutoDelay(40);
        robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7476; i++) {
            String holding = Integer.toString(i);
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.delay(4000);
            robot.mouseMove(144, 400);
            robot.delay(500);

            leftClick();
            //robot.delay(500);
            leftClick();

            robot.delay(10);


            type(holding);

            robot.mouseMove(450, 480);
            robot.delay(10);

            leftClick();
            robot.delay(500);
            leftClick();

            robot.delay(1000);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void leftClick() {
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(200);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(200);
    }

    private void type(int i) {
        robot.delay(40);
        robot.keyPress(i);
        robot.keyRelease(i);
    }

    private void type(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int code = b;
            // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
            if (code > 96 && code < 123)
                code = code - 32;
            robot.delay(40);
            robot.keyPress(code);
            robot.keyRelease(code);
        }
    }

    public static void typeCharacter(Robot robot, String letter) {
        try {
            boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0));
            String variableName = "VK_" + letter.toUpperCase();

            Class clazz = KeyEvent.class;
            Field field = clazz.getField(variableName);
            int keyCode = field.getInt(null);

            robot.delay(1000);

            if (upperCase)
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);

            if (upperCase)
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that can type letters and numbers:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotCharacter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( textField );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        typeCharacter(robot, "a");
        typeCharacter(robot, "b");
        typeCharacter(robot, "C");
        typeCharacter(robot, "D");
        typeCharacter(robot, "%");
     }

    public static void typeCharacter(Robot robot, String letter)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase( letter.charAt(0) );
            String variableName = "VK_" + letter.toUpperCase();

            Class clazz = KeyEvent.class;
            Field field = clazz.getField( variableName );
            int keyCode = field.getInt(null);

            robot.delay(1000);

            if (upperCase) robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );

            robot.keyPress( keyCode );
            robot.keyRelease( keyCode );

            if (upperCase) robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a part of this that I can implement in my for loop to solve my problem? I am not at all familiar with the Robot class, I am just trying to throw something quick and dirty together to automate this process.

Comment: Yes, I gave you the code to solve the problem. I demonstrate how to type one character at a time. Change your for loop to invoke the typeCharacter(...) method for each letter in the string.

Comment: Apparently I do not understand. I have modified my code so that it includes the typeCharacter method you posted, and changed my For loop to for(int i = 0; i>858;i++ ){
     String holding = Integer.toString(i);
     Robot robot = new Robot();
        typeCharacter(robot,holding);     
    }

It still types out nothing.

Comment: Did you run my code? Did it work because it works for me?. Text is typed into the text field of the GUI. I have proven the concept. Your code can't be executed because we have no idea how the mouse move code is relevant to our desktop, so I can't debug your program, only give you an example of working code. It is up to you to incorporate the working code into your class.

Comment: Your code runs fine, just doesn't do what I need. In mine the mouse moves are currently just moving the mouse around in a text editor. Eventually it will be used to click on the "file name" box of a save file dialog box and then move over to click the "enter" button. Currently I just have a Full screen Notepad open that has had the enter and space buttons clicked a load of times  so that text can be added anywhere on the screen. I run eclipse in a smaller-than-fullscreen view so that when the mouse makes it's first click, it is clicking on the notepad window.

Comment: Figured it out. Yay coding. I had an > instead of an <